# CakePHP & MongoDB connection using lewestoper Cakephp-monga

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, connection

I have cakePHP 3, MongoDB 3, PHP 5.6.
I am using the plugin https://github.com/lewestopher/cakephp-monga to connect CakePHP & MongoDB.

I get the error:

> Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found File
>   /var/www/cakephpmonga/vendor/league/monga/src/League/Monga/Connection.php
>   Line: 54